# Wordpress: So I've been calling wp_(tablenames) directly in mysql query. What's the best way to correct this?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

So I've been developing a plugin in wordpress, which has been running very slowly, and have been making database calls directly to wp_usermeta, which I've just found out you should never call directly, as follows:

```html
$getUserdaetails = pdo_query("Select wp_usermeta.user_id, Min(Case meta_key When 'name_of_your_facility' Then meta_value End) GYM_NAME, Min(Case meta_key When 'description_of_the_gym' Then meta_value End) GYM_DESCRIPTION, Min(Case meta_key When 'city_registration' Then meta_value End) GYM_CITY, Min(Case meta_key When 'country_registration' Then (SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY_MAPPING.COUNTRY_NAME FROM wp_usermeta, COUNTRY_MAPPING WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'country_registration' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value = COUNTRY_MAPPING.COUNTRY_CODE AND wp_usermeta.user_id = ?) End) GYM_COUNTRY, Min(Case meta_key When 'category' Then (SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY_MAPPING.CATEGORY_NAME FROM wp_usermeta, CATEGORY_MAPPING WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'category' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value = CATEGORY_MAPPING.CATEGORY_CODE AND wp_usermeta.user_id  = ?) End) GYM_CATEGORY, Min(Case meta_key When 'image_1' Then (SELECT wp_posts.guid FROM wp_usermeta, wp_posts WHERE wp_usermeta.user_id = ? AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'image_1' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'attachment' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value = wp_posts.ID) End) GYM_IMAGE FROM wp_usermeta, wp_posts, COUNTRY_MAPPING WHERE user_id = ?", pdo_real_escape_string($row1[user_id]), pdo_real_escape_string($row1[user_id]), pdo_real_escape_string($row1[user_id]), pdo_real_escape_string($row1[user_id]));
                     
$recordCountTest2 .= pdo_num_rows($getUserdaetails);
foreach($getUserdaetails as $row2){
 $html3a .= "Category - <span style='color: #000000;'>{$row2[GYM_CATEGORY]}</span>
 .........
 ";
}
```

My question is, how do I best change my code so that it becomes wordpress/plugin compliant?

Thanks

Comment: use $wpdb->prefix before table names instead of wp_. Also in wordpress use $wpdb for queries

Comment: Thanks for your response.I'm using the following, but no data is being returned. What's the issue? `$showcountry = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("Select distinct meta_value, COUNTRY_MAPPING.COUNTRY_NAME
                               from $wpdb->prefix usermeta, COUNTRY_MAPPING
                               where meta_key = '/country_registration'/
                               and meta_value = COUNTRY_MAPPING.COUNTRY_CODE"));

     if (!$showcountry) {
     }else{
          foreach($showcountry as $row){
         }
         echo json_encode($html, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Comment: If you wannt to use `$wpdb->prefix` then there is no space after that, example : `$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "tablename";`

Answer (score 0):

Always use $wpdb->prefix when run any sql query "Instead of wp_ ". like below example

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "liveshoutbox";
```